# send a ping packet using dev_queue_xmit

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

i have written a driver which sends a ping packet but its not working (i checked using tcpdump -i wlan0 icmp) . basically i have used ioctl call from an user program to start the transmission(its working)but there some problem in module code ,following is my code for transmission:

```
case WLAN_TRANSMIT :
                     icmp.type = ICMP_ECHO;
                     icmp.code = 0;
                     icmp.un.echo.sequence = i++;
                     icmp.un.echo.id = current->pid & 0xFFFF;
                     printk(KERN_ALERT"ID::%X\n",icmp.un.echo.id);
                     ip4.protocol = 0x01;                               //for icmp protocol
                     ip4.tos = 0x00;
                     ip4.frag_off = 0;
                     ip4.daddr = in_aton(procfs_buffer);
                     ip4.saddr = in_aton(ifr->ifr_addr.sa_data);
                     len = sizeof(data);
                     skb = dev_alloc_skb(1500);
                     skb->dev = __dev_get_by_name(&init_net,"wlan0");
                     skb_reserve(skb,NET_IP_ALIGN);  //header of 2 bytes; increments tail and data pointer
                     skb->data = skb_put(skb,sizeof(len)); // increments all pointer or adds data
                     memcpy(data,skb->data,len);
                    wdev = skb->dev;
                    skb->transport_header =skb_push(skb,sizeof(icmp));
                    memset(skb->transport_header,0,sizeof(struct icmphdr));
                    memcpy(skb->transport_header,&icmp,sizeof(struct icmphdr));

                    skb->network_header=skb_push(skb,sizeof(ip4));
                    memset(skb->network_header,0,sizeof(struct iphdr));
                    memcpy(skb->network_header,&ip4,sizeof(struct iphdr));
                   // printk("i::%d\n",i);
                  // skb->mac_header = skb_push(skb,6*sizeof(0xFF)); 
                    //skb->mac_header = ()
                    skb->mac_header = skb->dev->dev_addr;
                   if(dev_queue_xmit(skb)==NET_XMIT_SUCCESS)
                    printk(KERN_ALERT"success");
```

i am using dev_queue_xmit .

regards

karan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`skb->mac_header = skb->dev->dev_addr` looks wrong.
The MAC header must be copied into the packet, before the IP header, and `skb->data` must point to it. Setting `skb->mac_header` in this context is quite meaningless.

I also don't see that you calculate the IP and ICMP checksums (the ICMP checksum is, I think, optional, but the IP checksum is mandatory).

I really can't tell if it's all.
You should see what's the return value from `dev_queue_xmit`, and also print the packet contents, from `skb->data` to `skb->tail` and see they're a valid ICMP packet.

Comment: how could i calculate checksum for ip packet and icmp .... please see the last two lines of my code the return value for dev_queue_xmit is NET_XMIT_SUCCESS.....further for the copying of headers should be in order mac ip and icmp???

Comment: I'm not sure what's the easiest way to calculate checksums. Either find a kernel function, or write your own according to the specifications. About the return value - you should see what you got, and debug accordingly. If `dev_queue_xmit` failed, it's one thing, if it succeeded but there's no packet, it's another. And yes, the order is MAC, IP, ICMP.